# Make an HTML element move along a specific scrollbar, rather than the main scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fffc2e;
}

#first_screen {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10%;
 color: black;
 font-size: 50px;
 height: 100vh;
}

/*Navigation Button*/
#tutorialnav {
 z-index: 1;
 height:100%;
 width: 0;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #111;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: 0.2s;
 padding-top: 80px;
 filter: drop-shadow(5px 0px 1px black);
}

#tutorialnav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 transition: 0s;
 color: white;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.majornav {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.minornav {
 padding: 4px 8px 4px 64px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
 
#tutorialnav a:hover {
 color: yellow;
}

#navbtn {
 color: black;
 position: sticky;
 z-index: 2;
 font-size: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 10px;
 left: 20px;
 transition: 0.7s;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.noselect {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
/*End Navigation Button*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <title>3D Graphics Tutorial Homepage</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="3d Graphics Web Tutorials [Homepage]">
 <meta name="author" content="Harsha Boyilla">
 <meta name="keywords" content="3D, 3d, 3d graphics, 3D graphics, graphics, tutorial">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<body>
 <!-- Navigation Menu -->
 <div id="navigationmenu" class="noselect">
  <button id="navbtn">&#9776;</button>
  <nav id="tutorialnav">
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 2</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 3</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 4</a> 
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var navIsOpen = false;
  window.onload = function() 
  {
   document.getElementById("navbtn").onclick = function() 
   { 
    if(!navIsOpen)
    {
     document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "250px";
     document.getElementById("navbtn").style.color = "white";
     navIsOpen = true;
    }
    
    else if(navIsOpen)
    {
     document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "0px"
     document.getElementById("navbtn").style.color = "black";
     navIsOpen = false;
    }
     return false;
   }
  }
 </script>

 <article id="first_screen">
  <p>Welcome to my website!</p>
  <p>Placeholder text is placeholder text</p>
 </article>
</body>

</html>
```

On a website I'm creating I have a sidebar which acts as the navigation menu for the website. There is a button at the top left which opens and closes the scrollbar. If the sidebar has too many items, a scrollbar appears in order to scroll through the sidebar. The issue I'm having is that the button which opens and closes does not scroll along with the sidebar, but instead it scrolls when I scroll the main page. Is there a way to fix this? Here is the HTML and JavaScript I have so far.

```
    <div id="navigationmenu" class="noselect">
        <button id="navbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
        <nav id="tutorialnav">
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 1</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 2</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 3</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 4</a>  
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
                <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var navIsOpen = false;
        window.onload = function() 
        {
            document.getElementById("navbtn").onclick = function() 
            {   
                if(!navIsOpen)
                {
                    document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "250px";
                    document.getElementById("navbtn").style.color = "white";
                    navIsOpen = true;
                }

                else if(navIsOpen)
                {
                    document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "0px"
                    document.getElementById("navbtn").style.color = "black";
                    navIsOpen = false;
                }
                    return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Edit: WHOOPS forgot the CSS... here it is

```
#tutorialnav {
    z-index: 1;
    height:100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #111;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
    padding-top: 80px;
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 0px 1px black);
}

#tutorialnav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: 0s;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.majornav {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.minornav {
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 64px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#tutorialnav a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

#navbtn {
    color: black;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    transition: 0.7s;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
```

Edit 2: Figured out a solution - it's posted below. It unfortunately takes 48 hours before I can check my own solution, so this thread will be open for a little longer.

Comment: Welcome :) Can you share the minimal css styles of the button, the sidebar, body... You can also update your question with a snippet  (use the snippet button in the editor) where you can show us a preview of your actual design...

Comment: I inserted the snippet and my css, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Okay hope this is what you want. you need a seperate scroll button in the nav when it opens because the first on is sticky based on the entire screen.

Aside from that I changed the button tags to div so they look nice. Look at how the onclick fumction works. the way you had set the buttonit was looking for

`function openNav(){...}`
in your script tags but it wasn't there Good luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: #fffc2e;
        }

        #first_screen {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10%;
            color: black;
            font-size: 50px;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        /*Navigation Button*/

        #tutorialnav {
            z-index: 1;
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #111;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            transition: 0.2s;
            padding-top: 80px;
            filter: drop-shadow(5px 0px 1px black);
        }

        #tutorialnav a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            transition: 0s;
            color: white;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .majornav {
            padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .minornav {
            padding: 4px 8px 4px 64px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #tutorialnav a:hover {
            color: yellow;
        }

        #navbtn {
            color: black;
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 2;
            font-size: 36px;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 10px;
            left: 20px;
            transition: 0.7s;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        #navbtncls {
            color: blanchedalmond;
        }

        .noselect {
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigationmenu" class="noselect">

        <div id="navbtnopn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
        <nav id="tutorialnav">

            <div id="navbtncls" onclick="closeNav()">&#9776;</div>
            <a href="#temp" class="majornav">Part 1</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="majornav">Part 2</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="majornav">Part 3</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="majornav">Part 4</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
            <a href="#temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p>hello</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var navIsOpen = false;


        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "250px";
            navIsOpen = true;
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "0px"
            navIsOpen = false;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added the CSS, sorry about that. I changed the position to sticky, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: hope the addition is what you were looking for

Comment: Unfortunately, this messed up the CSS of the navbtn. The issue was that I needed navbtn to be within tutorialnav, in order to get proper scrolling, but I also did not want the CSS of tutorialnav elements to be applied to the navbtn. However, I was able to fix it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that has two buttons that replace each other while also keeping the transitions to look nice. Here it is. There is still one issue, which is that the button to close the menu is still clickable even if the sidebar is scrolled down, because the button to close the menu is actually the same one as the button to open the menu even though it doesn't appear that way. I tried to fix this by making both the close button and open button have their own onclick functions, but z-index isn't working the way I want it to so the clicks don't work properly. However, this is a high school project anyways so it's probably fine for now.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fffc2e;
}

#first_screen {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10%;
 color: black;
 font-size: 50px;
 height: 100vh;
}

/*Navigation Button*/
#tutorialnav {
 z-index: 1;
 height: 100%;
 width: 0;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #111;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: 0.2s;
 padding-top: 10px;
 filter: drop-shadow(5px 0px 1px black);
}

#tutorialnav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 transition: 0s;
 color: white;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.majornav {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.minornav {
 padding: 4px 8px 4px 64px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#tutorialnav a:hover {
 color: yellow;
}

#navbtnopen {
 color: black;
 position: sticky;
 z-index: 2;
 font-size: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 10px;
 left: 20px;
 transition: 0.2s;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

#navbtncls {
 color: black;
 position: sticky;
 z-index: 2;
 font-size: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 left: 20px;
 transition: 0.2s;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

.noselect {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
}
/*End Navigation Button*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <title>3D Graphics Tutorial Homepage</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="3d Graphics Web Tutorials [Homepage]">
 <meta name="author" content="Harsha Boyilla">
 <meta name="keywords" content="3D, 3d, 3d graphics, 3D graphics, graphics, tutorial">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<body>
 <!-- Navigation Menu -->
 <div id="navigationmenu" class="noselect">
  <span id="navbtnopen">&#9776;</span>
  <nav id="tutorialnav">
   <span id="navbtncls">&#9776;</span>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 2</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 3</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
   <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 4</a>     
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 5</a>     
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 6</a>     
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 7</a>     
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
            <a href="temp" class="majornav">Part 8</a>     
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 1</a>
    <a href="temp" class="minornav">Section 2</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var navIsOpen = false;
  window.onload = function() 
  {
   document.getElementById("navbtnopen").onclick = function() 
   { 
    if(!navIsOpen)
    {
     document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "250px";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.transition = "0s";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.opacity = "0";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.color = "black";
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.opacity = "1";
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.transition = "0.2s";
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.color = "white";
     navIsOpen = true;
    }
    
    else if(navIsOpen)
    {
     document.getElementById("tutorialnav").style.width = "0px"
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.transition = "0s";
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.opacity = "0";
     document.getElementById("navbtncls").style.color = "white";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.opacity = "1";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.transition = "0.2s";
     document.getElementById("navbtnopen").style.color = "black";
     navIsOpen = false;
    }
     return false;
   }
  }
 </script>

 <article id="first_screen">
  <p>Welcome to my website!</p>
  <p>Placeholder text is placeholder text</p>
 </article>
</body>

</html>
```